# How are libraries/modules like Standard C Library made?

Tags: java, c, shared-libraries, programming-languages, static-libraries

For example how the input/output library for C made.
Or libraries like odbc,vlcj,etc made.

Comment: They could be made in assembly language.

Comment: What is the question? Library is usually binary, which can be compiled from any (compiled) language

Comment: A library is a collection of code intended to one thing, or a type of thing well. Depending on the goal of the library, it might be able to be written in just the language itself (perhaps a bigint library for example), or might require system calls, drivers, etc (such as a socket library or similar).

Comment: Who says that libraries for a given language need to be written in that language?  Counterexamples abound.

Comment: How is this question too broad? It refers to a "turtles all the way down" problem that new programmers are bound to wonder about. I was about to write an answer when it got closed.

Comment: luther I want to know your answer.